# Why does my background-color of the menu only begin at the top-to-center of my image and not all?

Tags: html, css

What I have right now my background-color for `#nav-bar` won't show on the left side where I want it to show for all of the top in width (intuitively 100% width). It's weird because even though I stated width to be 100%, it is exactly the width size I want, but it's as if the background-color shifted to the right where there is only white space towards the right of my image. It starts at the middle where there first is text and ends at the very right which I stated, there is extra white space.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  border: 0;
}

#container {
  position: relative;
}

h1 {
  position: absolute;
  font-size: 90px;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 1000px;
  margin: -287px -100px 0px 0px;
}

#nav-bar {
  position: absolute;
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-size: 38px;
  top: 0;
  left: 31%;
  word-spacing: 30px;
}

#nav-bar {
  width: 100%;
  height: 70px;
  background-color: black;
}

#nav-bar {
  opacity: .30;
  filter: (opacity=30);
}

li {
  display: inline;
  color: white;
}

li a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

li a:hover {
  opacity: 0.5;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="container">
    <img src="...">
    <h1>IndieForwardMusic</h1>
    <ul id="nav-bar">
      <li id="li-1">Home</li>
      <li id="li-2">About</li>
      <li id="li-3">
        <a href="..."></a>
      </li>
      <li id="li-4">Contact</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because of your `#nav-bar` has `left: 31%` so it's starts from the middle. So set `left: 0` will fit into your container. Check below snippet for reference.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  border: 0;
}

#container {
  position: relative;
}

h1 {
  position: absolute;
  font-size: 90px;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 1000px;
  margin: -287px -100px 0px 0px;
}

#nav-bar {
  position: absolute;
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-size: 38px;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  word-spacing: 30px;
}

#nav-bar {
  width: 100%;
  height: 70px;
  background-color: black;
}

#nav-bar {
  opacity: .30;
  filter: (opacity=30);
}

li {
  display: inline;
  color: white;
}

li a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

li a:hover {
  opacity: 0.5;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="container">
    <img src="...">
    <h1>IndieForwardMusic</h1>
    <ul id="nav-bar">
      <li id="li-1">Home</li>
      <li id="li-2">About</li>
      <li id="li-3">
        <a href="..."></a>
      </li>
      <li id="li-4">Contact</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

change this class. try this.

```css
#nav-bar {
  position: absolute;
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-size: 38px;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  word-spacing: 30px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add overflow-x:hidden css in body

```
       body {
            margin: 0;
            border: 0;
            overflow-x: hidden;
        }

        #container {
            position: relative;
        }

        h1 {
            position: absolute;
            font-size: 90px;
            top: 100px;
            left: 0;
            text-align: center;
            width: 100%;
        }

        img {
            width: 100%;
            height: 1000px;
            margin: -287px -100px 0px 0px;
        }

        #nav-bar {
            position: absolute;
            list-style-type: none;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            font-size: 38px;
            top: 0;
            left: 31%;
            word-spacing: 30px;
        }

        #nav-bar {
            width: 100%;
            height: 70px;
            background-color: black;
        }

        #nav-bar {
            opacity: .30;
            filter: (opacity=30);
        }

        li {
            display: inline;
            color: white;
        }

        li a {
            text-decoration: none;
        }

        li a:hover {
            opacity: 0.5;
        }

 <body>
    <div id="container">
        <img src="...">
        <h1>IndieForwardMusic</h1>
        <ul id="nav-bar">
            <li id="li-1">Home</li>
            <li id="li-2">About</li>
            <li id="li-3">
                <a href="..."></a>
            </li>
            <li id="li-4">Contact</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</body>
```